# Entity Framework converting to async gives alot of errors

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

Im trying to make my Ef core repository asynchronous but im having some problems. All of these functions worked fine when it was not async

This function: Throws  An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'EntityFramework.Models.MyContext'.
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

```
    public async Task<bool> CreateSubAccountForUser(string userid, SubBankAccounts subBank)
    {
        var response =  await _bankRepository.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserID == userid);
        if (response == null)
            return false;

        response.SubBankAccounts?.Add(subBank);
        await _bankRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
```

this one dosent throw any error and just stop after FirstOrDefaultAsync have been hit. No other breakpoints on either returns got hit

```
  public async Task<Users> GetAllUserData(string userid)
  {
           var response = await _bankRepository.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserID == userid);
            if (response == null)
                return null;

            return response;
  }
```

program.cs
      
        builder.Services.AddDbContext(opt => opt
                .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                .UseMySql(config.GetConnectionString("mysql"), new MySqlServerVersion(new 
        Version())));

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<ILoginService, LoginService>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IBankRepository, BankRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IAdminService, AdminService>();
```

What have i missed? For me these functions seems so simple that there shouldent be any problems. As i have surfed around looking for fixes, i have noticed that ef core async seems to have its problems, like AddAsync and SaveChangesAsync() not always should be used and instead of Add and SaveChangesAsync(). Have i just missed a big part of EF core?

Comment: Since DbContext registered as Scoped, replace `AddTransient` with `AddScoped`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It should be fine to use a scoped dependency within a transient. It's more likely that an `await` has been missed somewhere.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, you are right. Usual problem here that await is missed. Or used something like `Task.WenAll`.